# Django Foreign Keys connections

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a model Field that has a OneToMany connections with TreeSensor and WeatherStation model. Im trying to pass over the queries of each treesensor/weatherstation model that match the id of each different field but get a `Field 'id' expected a number but got <built-in function id>.` .How do i fix that? Maybe change something on the `filter` ?

```
class Field(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    friendly_name = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=True)
    soil_type = models.CharField(max_length=24, choices=SOIL_TYPES, blank=True)  
    cultivation = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=CULTIVATIONS, blank=True)  
    kml = models.FileField(upload_to = user_directory_path_kml, null=True, blank=True)

class TreeSensor(models.Model):  
    field = models.ForeignKey(Field, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class WeatherStation(models.Model):
    field = models.ForeignKey(Field, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

**view**

```
def map(request):
    field_list = models.Field.objects.filter(user = request.user)
    tree_sensors = models.TreeSensor.objects.filter(field__pk = id)
    weather_stations = models.WeatherStation.objects.filter(field__pk = id)
    context = {
        "title": "Map",
        "field_list": field_list,
        "tree_sensors": tree_sensors,
        "weather_stations" : weather_stations,
    }
    template = 'agriculture/map.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: From where you're getting id? because you've not declared **id** anywhere python treating `id` as inbuild function

Comment: I don't see any declaration of `id`. and Pro Tip: remove `default=None` from `user` it didn't do anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your view you are filtering some field called `field` by `id`, which is not defined nowehere....

You have a queryset of Fields, so probably you should do something like this:

```
def map(request):
    field_list = models.Field.objects.filter(user = request.user).values_list('id', flat=True)
    tree_sensors = models.TreeSensor.objects.filter(field__id__in = field_list)
    weather_stations = models.WeatherStation.objects.filter(field__id__in = field_list)
```

Comment: Sorry for troubling you I've edited the full Field model to give u a better understanding .Again sorry im really noob at this .

Comment: @haduki Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: That's seems good, because `pk` is unique and we cannot apply filter on for accessing single object.

Comment: Yeah I get error `Failed lookup for key [kml] in 1`

Comment: @haduki I did one change, try again and let me know

Comment: @Walucas still error getting `Failed lookup for key [kml] in 1`

Comment: I tried `tree_sensors = models.TreeSensor.objects.filter(field__pk=models.TreeSensor.field_id)` and get `Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ForeignKeyDeferredAttribute object at 0x7fec0942a6a0>.`

Answer (score 0):

@Walucas your approach was correct it was kinda different though . It works out like this :
**view**

```
def map(request):

    field_list = models.Field.objects.filter(user = request.user)
    tree_sensors = models.TreeSensor.objects.filter(field_id__in = field_list.values_list('id',flat=True))
    weather_stations = models.WeatherStation.objects.filter(field_id__in = field_list.values_list('id',flat=True))
    context = {
        "title": "Map",
        "field_list": field_list,
        "tree_sensors": tree_sensors,
        "weather_stations" : weather_stations,
    }
    template = 'agriculture/map.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```